# Sort Array Of Objects By Number of Keys (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

Hi all I have an array of objects (20 of them) that I've placed in this format to make columns in an Angular Project (note there are objects in objects). I want to sort them by object with most keys (inside each object in array), to object with least number keys inside object in array) so that when they are displayed in columns it makes the most sense.

I'm mutating a navbar variable to use for a clickable advanced search.  Thanks for the help as this is my first big project as a new developer.

```js
var clickableFilters = [
  {"State": {
    "0": [{value: "liquid"}, {count: 30}]
    }
  },
  {"Country": {
    "0": [{value: "USA"}, {count: 50}]
    "1": [{value: "Nigeria"}, {count: 90}]
    }
  },
  {"Color": {
    "0": [{value: "blue"}, {count: 30}]
    "1": [{value: "purple"}, {count: 50}]
    "2": [{value: "green"}, {count: 100}]
    }
  }
 ]
```

How do I sort the objects by number of Keys (keys in inner object) so that it ends up (in JavaScript)

```
 [{"Color": {}}, {"Country": {}}, {"State": {}}]
```

Comment: Did you try the array sort method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Any reason for the down vote?

Comment: Hover your mouse over the down arrow, and read.

Comment: @squint actually noone is answering the question. Maybe you thought it was a bit simpler than it is.

Comment: *"This question does not show any research effort"*

Comment: @chrissavage i didn't downvote but you've misrepresented your data by using key names like `"least#OfKeysObject"` and `"secondMost#OfKeysObj"` that are not analogous to your actual data

Comment: @naomik I was trying to make it clear so that people didn't miss that there was an object inside. What would be a more appropriate name for the key?

Comment: @naomik It is an example to make the question more clear, it doesn't really matter what their name is.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes it does. Just grabbing the first property of any object, no matter what it might be is poor design. At some point presumably some other procedure will read these objects and need to access the nested objects; and it should be able to do so in a sane manner. It's the difference between `{key: 'x', value: 1}` and `{x:1}` – the former being way better than the latter.

Comment: @chrissavage *"What would be a more appropriate name for the key?"* – only you can tell us what the actual key is. If it were me, I wouldn't use a nested object at all if it doesn't serve any purpose. If you need to attach some other data along with the child object, then something like `{key: 'somekey', data: childObjectHere}` – that way the sort can always access the sortable property by a *known key*, `data`, instead of just grabbing whatever the first key of the input object would be.

Comment: @naomik good call on changing up the array. I tried to add a little clarity to the code.

Comment: @squint Thank you for the clarity. I could have mentioned I tried .sort but got confused by the nested nature of things. I will do better asking questions in the future.

Comment: @chrissavage if you have control over this, I think `let filters = [ ..., {filter: 'Country', options: [{value: 'blue', count: 30}, {value: 'purple', count: 50}, ...]}]` is a much better shape for the data.

Comment: @naomik I agree!  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution 1

Using a custom comparator for `Array.prototype.sort` does what you need it to do

```js
let data = [{a:1,b:2,c:3}, {a:1}, {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}, {a:1,b:2}]

data.sort((a,b) => Object.keys(a).length - Object.keys(b).length)

console.log(data)
```

#### Solution 2

If your data is nested, the child data should be attached to a property of a *known* name

```js
let data = [
  {foo: 'W', bar: {a:1,b:2,c:3}},
  {foo: 'X', bar: {a:1}},
  {foo: 'Y', bar: {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}},
  {foo: 'Z', bar: {a:1,b:2}}
]

let keyToSort = "bar";
data.sort((a,b) => Object.keys(a[keyToSort]).length - Object.keys(b[keyToSort]).length)

console.log(data)
```

---

#### Traps and pitfalls

On the other hand, if it is guaranteed to always have exactly one key (perhaps with an unknown/dynamic name), you could write

```
Object.keys(a[Object.keys(a)[0]]).length
```

This however is obviously very ugly and error prone (what if it *does* have more keys - or none at all). If you have control over the data structure, you should think about refactoring it, since an Object with only one key makes not much sense - you could as well just drop one nesting level.

---

#### It's your future

You should be in the habit of battling complexity — whenever it rears its stubborn head, grasp your staff and exert an equally stubborn force back upon it.

The first solution above appears somewhat manageable, but the second one starts to get pretty thick. If you break your solution down into tiny reusable parts, you can keep complexity at bay with relative ease.

```js
const ascComparator = (a,b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0

// use this if you want to sort data descending instead of ascending
const descComparator = (a,b) => ascComparator(b,a)

const prop = x => y => y[x]

const len = prop('length')

const comp = f => g => x => f (g (x))

const keylen = comp (len) (Object.keys)

let data = [
  {foo: 'W', bar: {a:1,b:2,c:3}},
  {foo: 'X', bar: {a:1}},
  {foo: 'Y', bar: {a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4}},
  {foo: 'Z', bar: {a:1,b:2}}
]

// same as solution #2 but much more descriptive
// "sort ascending using keylen of a.bar compared to keylen of b.bar"
data.sort((a,b) => ascComparator(keylen(a.bar), keylen(b.bar)))

console.log(data)
```

Breaking complexity down is a way of investing in your future. Once you wrap a bit of complexity up in its own procedure, it will always be at your disposal at a later time. Smaller procedures are also easier to test.

Each of the procedures above `ascComparator`, `prop`, `len`, `comp`, and `keylen` have *immediately apparent* intent. You can revisit these at any time and understand them with ease. And as a result of employing them, it makes your sort that much easier to read/write too.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that each object in the array actually only has one key with an object as a value.

Comment: Is there some common naming convention for the nested properties?  Is so, then you should still be able to address it with this answer by using `Object.keys(a.nestedProp).length - Object.keys(b.nestedProp).length`

Comment: @chrissavage can you paste the actual key for the parent object then? I'm sure they're not named things like `"least#OfKeysObject"` and `"secondMost#OfKeysObj"`. What are the actual keys?

Comment: @naomik You don't need to know them to answer. That's the point, but, yeah, you're quite right, in your comment below

Comment: @blex I understand that. But you *should* know them. Just grabbing the first property, whatever it might be, is haphazard and poor design. That's misuse of an object. It's the difference between `{key: 'x', value: 1}` and `{x:1}`

Comment: In my opinion the best answer, even if it is not directly applicable to the question. 1) mentioning sort 2) mentioning the concept of a custom comparator function 3) distilling it to a minimum 4) leaving some room for the OP to develop his/her own solution

Comment: @naomik Thanks for the help. I'm working on a project (been a developer for 3 months) and its all confidential information.  I'll edit it a bit more to try and add clarity

Comment: @Christoph thanks for the edit – very valuable information to have in the post ^_^

Comment: great detailed post @naomik Thank you

Comment: How many specific comparators like `ascComparator` are to be expected in practice? In other words, does a general comparator `comparator = f => x => y => f(x) (y) ? -1 : f(y) (x) ? 1 : 0;` make sense?

Comment: @LUH3417 custom comparators must always return `-1`, `0`, or `1`, so there's really no need for more than `ascComparator` and `descComparator` as *base* comparators. Because they're polymorphic and assume nothing about the structure of your data, you can sort by any value that is compatible with `>` and `<` – (These are more explicit than the subtraction-based (`-`) sorts that only work on Number types). Some languages actually offer `<=>` (coined "spaceship operator") which does a 3-way comparison; exactly what `ascComparator` is doing.

Comment: ... If you need to implement an arbitrary sort, you might find yourself wrapping one of the base comparators. – You *could* implement an even more basic `comparator` like you've described, and then implement `asc` and `desc` on top of that, but I'm not sure it's necessary. I updated my post to show how simple it is to declare `ascComparator`'s counter-part `descComparators`.

Comment: @LUH3417 upon further thought, your `compare` procedure would abstract the built-in `>` and `<` and allow use of any procedure. That's nice – We should come up with a use-case where that is beneficial to demonstrate `compare`'s overwhelming power !

Comment: `String.prototype.localCompare` comes to mind. Probably there are some other "edge cases". I've little experience with sorting - that's why I'm asking :D.

Answer (score 1):

For your data structure you can use `sort()` like this.

```js
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {"least#OfKeysObject": {
    key1: 'value',
    }
  },
  {"secondMost#OfKeysObj": {
    key1: 'value',
    key2: 'value'
    }
  },
  {"most#OfKeysObj": {
    key1: 'value',
    key2: 'value',
    key3: 'value'
    }
  }
 ];
 
 var result = arrayOfObjects.sort(function(a, b) {
   return Object.keys(b[Object.keys(b)[0]]).length - Object.keys(a[Object.keys(a)[0]]).length;
 });
 
 console.log(result)
```

Comment: `b[Object.keys(b)]` -> `b[Object.keys(b)[0]]`

Comment: @Vld: When the array has a single member, the `toString()` result is the same either way.

Comment: @squint I prefer to be explicit. Since it's a preference, I left it as a comment, not a proposed edit.

Comment: @Christoph: If the format of the object structure anticipates always having a single member, and they get more or fewer, then it's already broken. What if there are none? Would `"undefined"` be less broken? What if there are multiple but the one they need isn't first?

Comment: I totally agree. That is why I don't like this answer. However, adding a [0] is a bit more explizit than secretly relying on the toString() conversion, which is obvious for veterans but not for rookies like the OP seems to be.

Comment: @Christoph: *"...obvious for veterans but not for rookies"*. That's a valid point.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
arrayOfObjects.sort(function(a, b) {
    return Object.keys(a).length > Object.keys(b).length ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Comment: It misses the part when both, a and b are equal, and does not work with the above example.