# Sort Object Array based on key length/count in Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

consider Array of object in json format as below,

```
[
    {_id: "acd", employee: "jack"},
    {_id: "sdd", employee: "Monica", timeTaken: 0.6},
    {_id: "eee", employee: "Rose", timeTaken: 0.6, task: "GST"},
]
```

I simple want to sort the array of objects based on the number of keys in the object. If object has maximum number of keys then it must be place on the top.

Expected result is as below,

```
[       
    {_id: "eee", employee: "Monica", timeTaken: 0.6, task: "GST"},
    {_id: "sdd", employee: "Monica", timeTaken: 0.6},
    {_id: "acd", employee: "jack"},
]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982386/sort-array-of-objects-by-number-of-keys-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sort` to to sort the array of objects based on the number of keys in the object.

```js
var arr = [
    {_id: "acd", employee: "jack"},
    {_id: "sdd", employee: "Monica", timeTaken: 0.6},
    {_id: "eee", employee: "Rose", timeTaken: 0.6, task: "GST"},
];

arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return Object.keys(b).length - Object.keys(a).length;
});
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: sort mutates original array. No point in assigning to a new variable. Gives impression they are not the same

Comment: @charlietfl : Thanks for letting me know.